# How do async iterators work? error TS2504: Type must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I am trying out the "new" async generator/for dance:

```
async function* it() {
    yield "Hello";
    yield "World";
}

async function test() {
    for await (const x of it()) {
        console.log()
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error TS2504: Type must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator.
```

How can I make work?

What's the right "typesafe" return type for the "it" function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually fine, but async iterators are currently an ES.next feature, so you'll have to specify this ES version, e.g. by putting the following property in your tsconfig.json:

```
"target": "esnext"
```

**Transpiling**

If you want to transpile to a previous ES version, TypeScript will not handle this for you automatically. Instead, you can use `core-js`:

First, install core-js: `npm install core-js`

Then, edit tsconfig.json:

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "target": "es2015"
    [...]
  },
  [...]
}
```

Then, import core-js in to your source file:

```
import 'core-js/shim';
```

Comment: 1. Now do I make the iterator typesafe? 2. Can I transpill to older targets?

Comment: TypeScript should infer the type of the `it` function automatically. I added information for transpiling to my answer.

Comment: I still need a type since I want to generate an interface function*. Like “interface I { queryAll() : ???<string> }.

Comment: GOT IT WORKING! Remarks:
- it must be npm i core-js (not corejs)
- AsyncIterableIterator<T> is the return type of function*

Answer (score -1):

You need to shim `asyncIterator` Symbol.

```
(Symbol as any).asyncIterator = Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol.for('Symbol.asyncIterator');
```