# TS2504: Type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch

I'm trying to use the body of a fetch response as an async iterable in a new CRA React application.

```js
const response = await fetch('example.com');

if (response.ok && response.body) {
  for await (const b of response.body) {
    ...
  }
}
```

It should be possible [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body):

> The body read-only property of the Response interface is a ReadableStream of the body contents.

And:

> ReadableStream implements the async iterable protocol. This enables asynchronous iteration over the chunks in a stream using the for await...of syntax:

I already set the target to esnext in tsconfig.json according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221240/2625090), but I still get the error.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29867 seems related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that out of the browsers, only Firefox actually implements async iterable on ReadableStream as listed in the [compatibility table here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#browser_compatibility)

For this reason the official types do not include the method.

An alternative if running in node, and browser polyfill are [available from here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/65542#discussioncomment-6071004)

> if the code only runs in Nodejs, then do the type casting directly:
>
> ```
> import { default as stream } from 'node:stream'.
> import type { ReadableStream } from 'node:stream/web'.
>
> const response = await fetch('xxx')
> stream.Readable.fromWeb(response.body as ReadableStream<Uint8Array>)
> ```
>
> If the code needs to take into account the browser's runtime environment, you can add a polyfill:
>
> ```
> ReadableStream.prototype[Symbol.asyncIterator] = async function* () {
>   const reader = this.getReader()
>   try {
>     while (true) {
>       const {done, value} = await reader.read()
>       if (done) return
>       yield value
>     }
>   }
>   finally {
>     reader.releaseLock()
>   }
> }
> ```

If you are just running in a browser that implements the feature, adding this makes the compiler happy

```
interface ReadableStream<R = any> {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator](): AsyncIterableIterator<R>;
}
```